# Dropbox Core API list all folders

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

So I have been playing with Dropbox APIs for awhile. My app is retrieving all the image files from a user's dropbox via Core API.

Now I want to improve it a bit by allowing users to choose which folder to sync.. i.e. once they authorise the app, it will give them all the folders inside their account. Users can then choose one or many folder(s), the app will only retrieve image files from selected folders.

Is there a specific API that list out all folders inside a user's dropbox?

I'm not using any SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/<path>` gives you the details of the contents of directory

```
import requests
...
headers = ... # set up auth
...
params = { 'list' : 'true' }
response = requests.get('https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/<directory>', params=params, headers=headers)
subdirs = [d['path'] for d in response.json()['contents'] if d['is_dir'] == True]    
print(subdirs)
```

Comment: Thanks @achampion... I just found that and wanna edit my question :)

Comment: I have an additional question... say if a user has thousands of files in root dir (exceed file_limit). How can I get scan through then? I wish there's another param type=dir only...

Comment: You can add `{ 'filelimit' : 25000 }` to params, to increase from the default 10000, but AFAIK there isn't a way to just return directories.