# List all folders in a user's Dropbox

Tags: rest, dropbox-api

I know that the folder details can be obtained with the

`https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/<path>`

call. But, to call this API, we need a value for `<path>` right? Is there some way by which I can view all the folders at the root level in a Dropbox account?

I checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821637/dropbox-core-api-list-all-folders), but even that requires a value for `<directories>`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `/1/metadata/dropbox/` to get everything in the root.

Comment: oh, that was simple enough :D